Clang and libstdc++ compatibility: C++20 format header
Is there any documentation specifying which Clang versions are compatible with which libstdc++ versions for given C++ standard?
I would like to use C++20 and 'format' header.
I tried to compile on Ubuntu 24.04-like distro, with installed packages clang-15 libstdc++-14-dev libc++-15-dev using following command:
clang++-15 -v -O0 -g -std=c++20 -stdlib=libstdc++ UseFormat.cpp

following code:
#include <version>
// Check if relevant macro from C++20 is set in version header:
#ifdef __cpp_lib_format
    #include <format> // C++20
#endif

int main() { return 0; }

Compilation output (truncated):
Ubuntu clang version 15.0.7
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/lib/llvm-15/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name UseFormat.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debug-info-kind=constructor -dwarf-version=5 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/mat/Projekty -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/clang/15.0.7 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/14 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/clang/15.0.7/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -O0 -std=c++20 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/mat/Projekty -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-implicit-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/UseFormat-6c30ec.o -x c++ UseFormat.cpp
clang -cc1 version 15.0.7 based upon LLVM 15.0.7 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/14
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/backward
 /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/clang/15.0.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
In file included from UseFormat.cpp:4:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/format:43:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/array:43:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:71:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/bits/iterator_concepts.h:1013:13: error: no matching function for call to '__begin'
        = decltype(ranges::__access::__begin(std::declval<_Tp&>()));

Full compilation output: pastebin
Summing up, it seems that Clang 15 is not compatible with libstdc++ 14, beside the fact that according to cppreference 'format' header is supported by libstdc++ since version 13.
For comparison, the same source code compiles correctly, when libc++-15 is used, by the following command:
clang++-15 -v -O0 -g -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ UseFormat.cpp


In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../include/c++/14/format:43: I'm not sure why v15 should be using v14's headers. Is this an issue? Also, is this answer relevant?

You just happened to choose a libstdc++ version that has a bug which manifested only on Clang. It has been fixed since. Normally there is no need to match specific versions (except maybe if Clang is older than libstdc++ and doesn't implement necessary builtins or such).

@ken-y-n 14th version of libstdc++ is currently the newest available in Ubuntu 24.04 repository. Please keep in mind that, according to my understanding, libstdc++ is part of GCC project, not Clang/LLVM project, therefore it follows GCC release versions, not Clang/LLVM versions. Clang on Linux supports linking with either libc++ (LLVM impl. of C++ std. lib.) or libstdc++ (GCC impl. of C++ std. lib.)

@user17732522 would you mind to provide a link to bug report?

@morfis It seems I misremembered and the issue was actually fixed on the Clang side with Clang 16, see https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44178.
